# Flyway Hive Supported?

Tags: hive, flyway

Is Flyway support for Hive in 7.0.0 Release? Looked like it was being worked on in:

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/142
and
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1322/files

Answer (score 0):

Hive is not in the 7.0.0 release. We currently have no plans to add support for this database. To read more see our policy for adding support https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/contributingDatabaseSupport#why-doesnt-flyway-accept-all-database-support-contributions